# The buttons look and feel like they're being pushed

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap4.
The button appears in the footer component.

There is no problem when viewing on a PC, but when viewing on a smartphone, when I press the button, the button stays pressed.
How can I change the display to normal after the button is pressed, the same as on a PC?

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

footer.component.html

```
<button (click)="prevPage()" type="button" #prevBtn class="btn btn-block px-sm-3 px-md-5 btn-warning">
  prev <fa-icon [icon]="faAngleRight"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

footer.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('prevBtn', { static: false }) prevBtn: ElementRef;
prevPage() {
  this.router.navigate([this.prevHref]);
  this.prevBtn.nativeElement.blur();
}
```

---

use

- Angular 8.2.14
- Bootstrap 4.3.1

---

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-a7rhv1)

For Android + Chrome, hover? Active? will remain on the button.

[image]

Comment: The stackblitz works fine. Can you describe your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get rid of this.

Add `onclick` handler to the button element

```
onclick="this.blur()"
```

Hope it helps!

**More on this:**

This is a very common issue when you are using modals.

I have created a stackblitz to highlight the same issue using Angular Material.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qcqwyg

There are two buttons which just open up a dialog. One uses the `onclick` handler and one does not. You can see the difference when the dialog is closed. The depressed effect remains on the first button. (Tested on Chrome Browser).

The issue probably happens because the `blur` event is attached to `mouseup` event. `mouseup` event fires after the modal dialog is opened which disables all mouse click events for the elements in the background and as such the `blur` event is never triggered on the button and remains depressed.

Adding the `onclick` handler ensures that the `blur` event is executed immediately on click and the button gets released.

This is a common issue if you use Angular Material Schematics to generate a `nav`. the default navigation created has this issue on the menu button (also referred to as "Hamburger button")

Hope this helps others who may be facing same issues.

Comment: Perhaps because of page transition instead of modal display, this method did not solve it.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the issue. It would be easier to find the cause of the issue and solve it.

Comment: Added a link to stackblitz.